# Mean and Standard Deviation of a Set in Set-Builder Notation

Tags: notation

Say we have set $C_{mc} = \{ x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n \}$ and we want to show a calculation of the mean ($\mu_c$) and the standard deviation ($\sigma_c$) for this set. Do the following equations make sense? Or is there a better way to show this using set notation?

\begin{equation}
    \mu_c = \cfrac{\sum C_{mc} }{\lvert C_{mc} \rvert}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
    \sigma_c = \sqrt{\frac{\sum \{ x - \mu_c \mid x \in C_{mc} \}^2}{\lvert C_{mc} \rvert}}
\end{equation}

Comment: $\bar{x} = \frac{1}{|C|} \sum_{x \in C} x$ and $s= \sqrt{\frac{1}{|C|} \sum_{x \in C} (x-\bar{x})^2}$ is more conventional